# Does Bullet collision detection library provide boolean operations on worl objects geometry?

Tags: c++, bullet

I need something alike [CGAL gives in terms of simple boolean operations on top of 3d meshes](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Nef_3/Chapter_main.html) but in lib Bullet. So I wonder if there is 3D Boolean Operations on meshes in Bullet? (cant find any dedicated chapter in [manual](http://www.bulletphysics.com/ftp/pub/test/physics/Bullet_User_Manual.pdf), am I blind?)